Yes God forgives, but how does one forgive himself?
So as far as I understand it, it is the case that if one prays, asks for forgiveness and repents and baptizes then according to most denominations and the Bible God forgives the sin one has committed.
However what I can't quite wrap my head around is how to forgive oneself.
Forgiving oneself in this context means (please use your own definition if mine isn't accurate enough):

Accepting that one has committed sin
Not beating oneself up/self criticism anymore because of the sin
No feelings of resentment or vengeance towards oneself
No destructive feeling of regret (still regretting but not the kind impeding with daily life or mental health)
No destructive guilt or shame (similar to regret: A little guilt/shame is not the problem, but to much of it risks mental health)

While it might be easier to forgive single mistakes, it's a lot more difficult to handle character weaknesses or repeating sin. Is there any additional information about that?
Summarized Question:

What does the Bible/the denominations say about self forgiveness?
How can one forgive oneself?
What steps can one do to forgive oneself?
Is the process to self-forgiveness fundamentally different for specific sins?
How can one forgive character weaknesses or repeating sin?


Talk to a pastor/priest. That's who you should be asking, both as a matter of this SE's policies, and because they're more likely to be able to help. That said, some advice I came across here that may be useful: don't focus on your sin, but focus on following Christ.

@Matthew Thank you for your advice. Follow up though: Is there no general answer to this, or am I the only one having a problem with self-forgiveness?

All of the above statements are answered in Romans Chapter 7 by the apostle Paul. In that chapter Paul expresses his own inner conflict regarding his own inward covetousness.

Let me restate: I am suggesting that "talk to a pastor/priest" is an answer, possibly even the "best" answer. Also, saying that a Question is against the SE's policies (although it seems others disagreed enough to Answer) isn't saying there isn't an answer.

If you could eliminate yourself from the question, the reason for closing would go away. As it stands now, the Title contains an "I" and a "me", and the body a "me".  It shouldn't be difficult to change this into an objective question.

The question focuses on personal sin, within the self.
In Romans Chapter Seven Paul deals with exactly that matter and deals with it not in some vague way but deals with it precisely in regard to the law. The particular sin which Paul mentions is covetousness, an inward fault which nobody outside can even detect occurring.
Therefore the soul must deal with this in regard to God almighty and in regard to the self which is the subject and the object of the inquiry.
The question speaks of 'forgiveness' a rather vague term. 'Remission' is that used in the bible. Which depends upon sacrifice and justification. (Not a mere 'forgiving' without any respect to righteousness.)

What shall we say then? Is the law sin? God forbid. Nay, I had not known sin, but by the law: for I had not known lust, except the law had said, Thou shalt not covet. But sin, taking occasion by the commandment, wrought in me all manner of concupiscence. For without the law sin was dead.
For I was alive without the law once: but when the commandment came, sin revived, and I died. And the commandment, which was ordained to life, I found to be unto death. For sin, taking occasion by the commandment, deceived me, and by it slew me. Wherefore the law is holy, and the commandment holy, and just, and good.
Was then that which is good made death unto me? God forbid. But sin, that it might appear sin, working death in me by that which is good; that sin by the commandment might become exceeding sinful.
For we know that the law is spiritual: but I am carnal, sold under sin. For that which I do I allow not: for what I would, that do I not; but what I hate, that do I. If then I do that which I would not, I consent unto the law that it is good. Now then it is no more I that do it, but sin that dwelleth in me. For I know that in me (that is, in my flesh,) dwelleth no good thing: for to will is present with me; but how to perform that which is good I find not.
For the good that I would I do not: but the evil which I would not, that I do. Now if I do that I would not, it is no more I that do it, but sin that dwelleth in me.
I find then a law, that, when I would do good, evil is present with me. For I delight in the law of God after the inward man: But I see another law in my members, warring against the law of my mind, and bringing me into captivity to the law of sin which is in my members.
O wretched man that I am! who shall deliver me from the body of this death? I thank God through Jesus Christ our Lord. So then with the mind I myself serve the law of God; but with the flesh the law of sin.

[Romans Chapter Seven - KJV - vs 7-25]
Note that the remedy in the Gospel, the doctrine of Christ, is covered in detail by Paul in the following chapters of the epistle to the Romans, wherein he covers reconciliation, justification, remission and sanctification.

Interesting. Romans 8,1 also says: "There is therefore now no condemnation for those who are in Christ Jesus." But what I don't get is how to get out of the self-condemnation. From Romans 7 I would say that Paul even shares my sentiment on the difficulty of impossibility of self-forgiveness. Again it kind of easy to understand that God forgives, but I might not understand how the following verses (8,2-6) work in practice and how they enable Remission.

We have to believe we are forgiven. Read Scriptures such as Micah 7:19 , Psalm 103:12 and following etc... Also there is a difference between repentance and remorse. Are we just remorseful, sorry for the wrong we have done but are not troubled by it, then we will not feel forgiven and keep beating ourselves up. A true repentance  means turning away from the sin and being troubled by it.

The Bible does show the steps that believers should take to self-forgive, once they know God's forgiveness has been applied to them through the shed blood of Christ. The answers so far would provide an excellent collation if put together. But there is one text that might get you "over the hump", so to speak, in order to progress in this endeavour. It has not yet be mentioned. I now detail it in the hope that all that has gone before will lose a little bit of 'fuzz' and come better into focus.
It is Paul's counsel regarding how they are to rejoice in the Lord always - which will be impaired if one remains with feeling of unshakable remorse at certain things they are prone to repeat. Paul raises the wonder of this greatest gain in Christ. He speaks of 'winning Christ'...

"And to be found in him, not having mine own righteousness, which is
of the law, but that which is through the faith of Christ, the
righteousness which is of God by faith... I follow after, if that I
may apprehend that for which also I am apprehended of Christ Jesus.
Brethren, I count myself not to apprehended: but this one thing I do,
forgetting those things which are behind, and reaching forth unto
those things which are before, I press toward the mark of the prize of
the high calling of God in Christ Jesus." Philippians 3:7-14 A.V.

Notice how all the focus has to switch from self to Christ? Paul was "the worst of sinners" and if anyone had cause to remain spiritually crippled by his awful sins, he did. But he was healed by Christ and started to live for Christ, who enabled him to grow to useful spiritual maturity.
Even though Paul now had faith in Christ, notice how he wrote of righteousness "which is through the faith of Christ"? He wasn't focused on his own level, or consistency, of faith. It was the faith of Christ that brought about the righteousness which is of God by faith. Once Paul had grasped that, he knew Christ and the power of Christ's resurrection, and fellowship with him. Nothing could separate him from that fellowship.
All that needs to be seen at this point is Christ, and no longer self. Un-Christ-like things need to be shoved out of sight (even literally), as past history. The things of earth seem strangely dim when you look full in his wonderful face. Nobody can do that while looking behind themselves at either old, or very recent sins. The less thought is given to such acts of self, the less likely they are to exercise any pull, or attraction. The shackles are broken by what Christ did. The question is, are they still seen as being round the ankles, even though they are unlocked?

One place to start is in 2 Corinthians:

For godly grief produces a repentance that leads to salvation without
regret, whereas worldly grief produces death. - 2 Corinthians 7:10

This letter deals with the emotions and with finding comfort from God during trials.

Blessed be the God and Father of our Lord Jesus Christ, the Father of
mercies and God of all comfort, who comforts us in all our affliction,
so that we may be able to comfort those who are in any affliction,
with the comfort with which we ourselves are comforted by God. 2 Corinthians 1:3-4

Of course the above must be in the context of the church community. We need to be part of the flow of comfort, offering it to others and receiving it ourselves.
Another place to turn is the Psalms. Some grief is because your repentance is incomplete. Psalm 51 gives an example of full repentance.
If your feelings are tangled up with mourning a great loss, turn to Job.
There are times when you must seek the forgiveness of a person you have offended.
After considering many other possible remedies, you may discover that your problem is idolatry. Our own sense of our need to forgive ourself makes that an idol, where we think that we must put ourself into the seat of Christ and somehow add something that was lacking in his death on the cross.
On the other hand, the trouble may spring from lacking or forgetting the security of your salvation. Romans speaks extensively about how secure is our place in God's love once we have been saved. Both the sins within (Romans 7) and the terrors without (Romans 8) are covered.

Interesting answer. So to give a bit more insight to the problem: It is more a form of self-judging, meaning I think X is wrong, abhorrent and reprehensible, and I did X and not only did I do X once I did it repeatedly. The shame, regret, guilt and self-criticism didn't stop after receiving God's forgiveness (at least that is my current understanding of it). It might be the case of idolatry as you say, since I seem to still judge myself. But I guess this is going into a more personal realm and beyond the realm of C.SE.

Believe:
In the forgiveness of sins.
Believe God gave his best to save you from your sins, he gave his only Son, God was manifest in the flesh and took the punishment for our sins, 1 Tim 3:15.
Believe all the promises of God (and find a promise which suits your condition).
You are not the chief of sinners - Paul was, 1 Timothy 1:15.
It isn't just that your sins are forgiven, you have a robe of righteousness given. The Law is no longer able to condemn you because you died to the law when you were baptised into His death, when He died you died with Him.
The worst sinners become the best saints.
Unbelief doesn't help.
To despondently look at sin when God bids us look to Jesus is itself a sinful look.
Knowing we are forgiven leads to joy, joy unspeakable and full of glory, and this joy (of the Lord) is our strength, Nehemiah 8:10.
Believe there is a Holy Spirit to help you.
Look to the cross as your only hope.
Remember you are not alone, ALL have sinned and fall short of the Glory of God.
The Gospel is for people just like you, and for people in exactly your condition, while we were yet without strength Christ died for us, Romans 5.
So believe in the goodness of God, rejoice in his goodness, this is joy, not rejoicing in our goodness because we don't have any.  Rejoice in God not in yourself.
Let the knowledge of your own weakness humble you, but not make you despair, humbly ask for help from God, believe you are his child (because you have believed in the Lord Jesus), and he will give you what you ask, Romans 8:32, Luke 11:9-13.


You sin.
You recognize that you have sinned.
You regret that sin.
You repent of that sin (you change your attitude and behaviour) so that you will never want to do it again.
You accept responsibility for the consequences of your sin.
You do what you can to undo the harm.
You accept forgiveness from God.

At this point, you are no longer the same person that sinned: you have developed a much stronger and more nearly God-like character.

Punishment is pointless.
Dwelling on your past is counter-productive.
God has forgiven you.
You have developed a much stronger and more nearly God-like character.
You are no longer the same person that sinned, so there is no need to forgive yourself, there is nothing to forgive.

As an analogy, compare it with learning a sport.

Every day you practice and month by month you get better at it.
Why would there be any need to forgive yourself for being so relatively bad at it last year?


Contrition and repentance are per-requisites to God forgiving you for intentional sins; and what better act of contrition than to own up to your mistake and to do what you can to make it right? Make an honest effort to be reconciled to those you have wronged. That's not to say that God's forgiveness is contingent upon them forgiving you - but you will find a weight lifted off your heart if you know you did what you reasonably could to mend the relationship and any inflicted damage. And, of course, dedicate yourself to not repeating your sins that you not bring this harm upon others again nor this guilt upon yourself.

Matthew 5:23-24  Therefore, if you are presenting your offering at the altar, and there you remember that your brother has something against you, 24 leave your offering there before the altar and go; first be reconciled to your brother, and then come and present your offering.

